# VB.NET UPDATE Method

Tags: vb.net

Good day everyone. I would like to ask for help regarding my code to update specific record in the database. My back-end is Microsoft Access and front-end is Visual Basic. It gives me an error "No value given for one or more required parameters". Also, I receive a problem about "object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Here's my code. Thank you :)

```
    Private Sub UpdateClient()

    Dim sqlUpdateClient As String = "UPDATE tblClient SET clientCompany = @clientCompany, clientStreetAddress = @clientStreetAddress, clientCity = @clientCity, clientContactPerson = @clientContactPerson, clientContactNumber = @clientContactNumber, clientEmail = @clientEmail, clientMobileNumber = @clientMobileNumber WHERE clientID = " + selectedClient
    Dim recordsAffected As Integer = 0
    Dim accessCommand As New OleDbCommand(sqlUpdateClient, accessConnection)
    accessCommand.CommandText = sqlUpdateClient

    accessCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@clientCompany", txtClientCompany.Text)
    accessCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@clientStreetAddress", txtClientStreetAddress.Text)
    accessCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@clientCity", txtClientCity.Text)
    accessCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@clientContactPerson", txtClientContactPerson.Text)
    accessCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@clientContactNumber", txtClientPhoneNumber.Text)
    accessCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@clientEmail", txtClientEmailAddress.Text)
    accessCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@clientMobileNumber", txtClientMobileNumber.Text)

    Try

        accessConnection.Open()
        recordsAffected = accessCommand.ExecuteNonQuery

    Catch ex As Exception

        lblError.Text = ex.ToString

    Finally

        accessConnection.Close()

    End Try

    If recordsAffected = 0 Then
        MsgBox("Record updated failed!", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, "Project Analysis System")
    Else
        MsgBox("Record updated successfully!", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Project Analysis System")
        PopulateClientList()
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Where are `accessConnection` and `selectedClient` defined and what is the definition of table `tblClient`?

Comment: Where are you receiving "object reference not set to an instance of an object"? Also, why not assign selectedClient as a parameter @clientID?

Comment: @vane: The accessConnection contains my connection string, while the selectedClient comes from the listview, in which when I select an item from the listview, it returns an integer.

Comment: @astander: When I tried to create a parameter "clientID", it gives me the error of "No value given for one or more required parameters". One time, when I have tried to concatenate the SQL string with a variable, it worked, but not in my other forms, considering all replacements to variables and names.

Comment: I don't believe that Access supports named parameters does it?  Instead use question marks in your UPDATE string instead of named parameters and then be sure to add the parameters to the accessCommand object in the correct order.

Comment: @Ju-chan We can't see the code that creates/assigns values to `accessConnection` and `selectedClient` so my inclination is to point at those as a problem if not THE problem. Please provide the code that creates/assigns these variables. Also, if you gave us the exact line the error occurs, that would be very very helpful!

Comment: @ChrisDunaway You are correct; when an OleDbCommand is set to Text, which is the default, it does not support named parameters. Use `?` instead of the `@parameterName` format and make sure you add them to the collection in the correct order. See [OleDbCommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.parameters.aspx) for more information (in particular the first sentence of the Remarks section).

Comment: @vane: I'll update the post as soon as possible.

Comment: Thanks for this discussion. I have made it work thanks to John Woo's help and thanks for everyone's ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is `accessConnection` a global (*connection object*) variable? You must have created another instance of that object on that procedure.

One more thing, `clientID` is also be parameterized. then add this line

```
accessCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@clientID", selectedClient)
```

**UPDATE 1**

```
Private Sub UpdateClient()

    Dim recordsAffected As Integer = 0
    Dim sqlUpdateClient As String = "UPDATE tblClient " & _
                                    "SET clientCompany = ?, " & _
                                    "   clientStreetAddress = ?, " & _
                                    "   clientCity = ?, " & _
                                    "   clientContactPerson = ?, " & _
                                    "   clientContactNumber = ?, " & _
                                    "   clientEmail = ?, " & _
                                    "   clientMobileNumber = ? " & _
                                    "WHERE clientID = ?"

    Using accessConnection As New OleDbConnection("connectionStringHere")
        Using accessCommand As New OleDbCommand()
            With accessCommand
                .Connection = accessConnection
                .CommandType = CommandType.Text
                .CommandText = sqlUpdateClient
                .Parameters.AddWithValue("clientCompany", txtClientCompany.Text)
                .Parameters.AddWithValue("clientStreetAddress", txtClientStreetAddress.Text)
                .Parameters.AddWithValue("clientCity", txtClientCity.Text)
                .Parameters.AddWithValue("clientContactPerson", txtClientContactPerson.Text)
                .Parameters.AddWithValue("clientContactNumber", txtClientPhoneNumber.Text)
                .Parameters.AddWithValue("clientEmail", txtClientEmailAddress.Text)
                .Parameters.AddWithValue("clientMobileNumber", txtClientMobileNumber.Text)
                .Parameters.AddWithValue("clientID", selectedClient)
            End With
            Try
                accessConnection.Open()
                recordsAffected = accessCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
            Catch ex As OleDBException
                lblError.Text = ex.Message.ToString()
            Finally
                accessConnection.Close()
            End Try

            If recordsAffected = 0 Then
                MsgBox("Record updated failed!", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, "Project Analysis System")
            Else
                MsgBox("Record updated successfully!", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Project Analysis System")
                PopulateClientList()
            End If
        End Using
    End Using

End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: @JohnWoo clientID isn't required to be parameterized; it's best practice but will work without making it a parameter and concatenating it like he's doing.

Comment: @vane it's weird when you supply parameters with the other values and some don't. anyway, it's the user's choice.

Comment: @JohnWoo I completely agree and think it should be parameterized as well, I just don't want misinformation floating around as you say it **must** be parameterized and this statement is false.

Comment: @JohnWoo: Yes, accessConnection is my OleDbConnection. But I have just placed that line of code in my global section. I don't know if it is just me, or my code is really wrong, but when I used the same sequence, same objects from toolbox, same names, and same parameters, it works, and sometimes it doesn't.

Comment: Are there other details that you guys need to help me with my problem?

Comment: @Ju-chan can you please try my updated answer? hope it will work now.

Comment: @Ju-chan see this [*Parameter Queries in ASP.NET with MS Access*](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/26/Parameter-Queries-in-ASP.NET-with-MS-Access)

Comment: @JohnWoo: I'll give that link a try. I'll get you all back when I've tried everything.